# How to concatenate instream dataset and normal sequential dataset using IEBGENER?

Tags: mainframe, jcl

Trying to concatenate instream dataset and normal sequential dataset using IEBGENER throws error concatenated dataset LRECLS not equal or RECFMS different. Unable to set DCB LRECL and RECFMS for instream dataset. Rest of the datasets are VB with LRECL 2500.

Comment: Can you share the JCL in the step ?

Comment: Please tell us about the instream data... Is it from  DD * as 80 char records or is it 2500 char?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use IEBGENER with the different LRECLs. You will need a preliminary step that copies the instream data into a temporary data set with the same attributes as the others, then use IEBGENER, with this temporary data set in the place of the instream data.

There are two easy ways of copying: 1) use the SORT utility specifying SORT FIELDS=COPY for the input; 2) use IDCAMS with a REPRO statement. You can also use IEBGENER, but it’s a bit trickier; I don’t recommend it. (IEBGENER requires use of `SYSIN` control cards in this case.)

Answer (score 0):

Make dataset of instream data with the same length of another dataset and then concatenate. If you keep instream data in the jcl, it will be 80 length and you will get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do it within JCL:

```
//BUF       DD DSN=&&BUF,SPACE=(TRK,(6,18)),DISP=(NEW,PASS)
//CAC       DD DSN=&&CAC,SPACE=(TRK,(6,18)),DISP=(NEW,PASS)
//CONCAT    DD DSN=*.BUF,VOL=REF=*.BUF,DISP=(OLD,DELETE)
//          DD DSN=*.CAC,VOL=REF=*.CAC,DISP=(OLD,DELETE)
```